# RGoogleAnalytics - start.date before August 2016

Tags: r, google-analytics

I use RGoogleAnalytics for reporting website stats in our company. Today I saw that the data are only shown from 1st of August 2016 (instead of 1st of June 2016), even if I use

```
end.date <- as.character(today())

query.list <- Init(start.date = "2016-06-01",
               end.date = end.date,
               dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:month", "ga:country", "ga:city", "ga:networkDomain", "ga:pagePath"),
               metrics = c("ga:users", "ga:newUsers"),
               max.results = 30000,
               sort = "-ga:date",
               table.id = "ga:321009211")
```

in my script. Has anybody experienced a similar problem and knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting your results by decreasing date (ie last dates first) and you have a max 30K results, so there is no guarantee those 30K results lines will be enough to go back to June 2016.

You can:

- increase the max number of results (API v4 supports 100K via [pageSize](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size))
- or break up your query into multiple queries with smaller time ranges

Comment: This was also my first thought, but I have only 19,971 results in my query. Also, I made a query from 1st of June 2016 to 1st of July 2017 and it started with August 2016.

Comment: Might sound silly but better safe than sorry: and in the GA interface you do have data for June 2016 for the specific view `ga:321009211`?

Comment: not a silly question, I sometimes cannot see the simple solution in complicated cases. but in this case, yes, data for June 2016 are available via the GA interface.